# Fit bipolar sigmoid python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm stuck trying to fit a bipolar sigmoid curve - I'd like to have the following curve:

[image]

but I need it shifted and stretched. I have the following inputs:

```
x[0] = 8, x[48] = 2
```

So over 48 periods I need to drop from 8 to 2 using a bipolar sigmoid function to approximate a nice smooth dropoff. Any ideas how I could derive the curve that would fit those parameters?

Here's what I have so far, but I need to change the sigmoid function:

```
import math

def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))


plt.plot([sigmoid(float(z)) for z in range(1,48)])
```

Comment: `atan` and `atanh` are popular sigmoid functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From generic bipolar sigmoid function:

```
f(x,m,b)= 2/(1+exp(-b*(x-m))) - 1
```

there are two parameters and two unknowns - shift `m` and scale `b`

You have two condition:f(0) = 8, f(48) = 2

take first condition, express `b` vs `m`, together with second condition write non-linear function to solve, and then use `fsolve` from SciPy to solve it numerically, and recover back `b` and `m`.

Here related by similar method question and answer: [How to random sample lognormal data in Python using the inverse CDF and specify target percentiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935843/how-to-random-sample-lognormal-data-in-python-using-the-inverse-cdf-and-specify)

Answer (score 3):

You could redefine the sigmoid function like so

```
def sigmoid(x, a, b, c, d):
    """ General sigmoid function
    a adjusts amplitude
    b adjusts y offset
    c adjusts x offset
    d adjusts slope """
    y = ((a-b) / (1 + np.exp(x-(c/2))**d)) + b
    return y

x = np.arange(49)
y = sigmoid(x, 8, 2, 48, 0.3)

plt.plot(x, y)
```

Severin's answer is likely more robust, but this should be fine if all you want is a quick and dirty solution.

```
In [2]: y[0]
Out[2]: 7.9955238269969806

In [3]: y[48]
Out[3]: 2.0044761730030203
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also use `curve_fit` which might come in handy if you have more than just two datapoints. The output looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the graph contains the desired data points. I used @lanery's function for the fit; you can of course choose any function you like. This is the code with some inline comments:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sigmoid(x, a, b, c, d):
    return ((a - b) / (1. + np.exp(x - (c / 2)) ** d)) + b

# one needs at least as many data points as parameters, so I just duplicate the data
xdata = [0., 48.] * 2
ydata = [8., 2.] * 2

# plot data
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'bo', label='data')

# fit the data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata, p0=[1., 1., 50., 0.5])

# plot the result
xdata_new = np.linspace(0, 50, 100)
plt.plot(xdata_new, sigmoid(xdata_new, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```